# Facebook API share_count newly reports as 0 for all pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have lots of shares on a URL but it is reporting as zero as with all other stories on my domain as of today (was working yesterday).    It also reports as zero on FB share debugger... what gives?

[image: pic from graph explorer]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1177868239258536/

Answer (score 0):

You can still see the total amount here, that's the amount summed up until ~39 hours ago, after that nothing is getting picked up, not shares not likes.

Examples:

- https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://stackoverflow.com/
- [https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object{engagement}&id=https://stackoverflow.com/](https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object%7Bengagement%7D&id=https://stackoverflow.com/)
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https://stackoverflow.com/

The specific problem you just reported has been confirmed by one other person in the Bugs Support section.

**UPDATE**

It was an acknowledged bug - https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/299217137823945/ - and it was solved less than 24 hours after one of their team members assigned the report to the appropriate team. Good luck.